# Does a up to date boilerplate for Bootstrap 4 with live reload, sass and js build exist?

Tags: assets, frontend, bootstrap-craft

I'm pretty new to Craft, and a noob when it comes to build tools. Coming from WordPress I've been using Roots/Sage which is a starter theme with liveReload(browserSync), Bootstrap 4, SASS and JS compiling.

I've been googling for a long time now, and I haven't been able to find a good boilerplate for me to start doing development on.

What build tool isn't really important to me(WebPack, Gulp, etc.).

What I'm looking for is:

- liveReload, CSS-injection or simple browserSync. So when I'm updating my SASS styles and Craft templates the site automatically updates.
- Bootstrap 4
- JS concatenation and uglyfing

Is there anything out there that fits my(and I know a lot of other developers) needs?

Answer (score 1):

Craft doesn't use themes, in the way WordPress does, so you won't find a direct equivalent to Roots / Sage.

That said, none of what you listed is CMS-specific, so there's nothing stopping you setting up a generic development / build workflow which matches your stated requirements.

Stack Overflow is a better place to ask about general tooling, though.